# Maximum area of specific quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a convex quadrilateral. Lines $AC$ and $BD$ are perpendicular and $AB+CD=8$. Find the maximum area of $ABCD$.

Let $O$ be intersection of the diagonals. Notice that the area of the quadrilateral is $\frac{1}{2} (AO+OC)(BO+OD) \leq \frac{1}{4} (\sum AO^2 + 2AO \cdot OC + BO \cdot OD )$ (By AM-GM).

On the other hand $\sqrt{AO^2+BO^2}+\sqrt{CO^2+DO^2}=8$. The last equation yields: $\sum AO^2 + 2\sqrt{(AO^2+BO^2)(CO^2+DO^2)}=64$.

Can this equations be helpful? Any hint or solution will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to avoid no-clue questions. Regardless, you can still provide context. What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: Sorry, I will try to provide something.

Comment: +1, thank you very much for providing detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $AO=a$, $BO=b$, $CO=c$, $DO=d$, then problem is the following: $$a,b,c,d> 0,\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2}=8, S=\frac{1}{2}(a+c)(b+d)={\rm max}$$
$$(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2=2a^2+2b^2 \Rightarrow (a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)\Rightarrow\\ a+b\leq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
$$c+d\leq\sqrt{2}\sqrt{c^2+d^2}$$
$$a+b+c+d\leq\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{c^2+d^2})=8\sqrt{2}$$
$$a+c=x,b+d=y\Rightarrow x+y\leq 8\sqrt{2}$$
$$(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2=4xy\Rightarrow 4xy\leq (x+y)^2\leq 128\Rightarrow xy\leq 32$$
$$S=\frac{1}{2}xy\leq 16$$
$$S_{\rm max}=16$$
$S=S_{\rm max}=16$ at $x-y=0$, $a-b=0$, $c-d=0$ ($x-y=0$ is automatically true at $a-b=0$ and $c-d=0$).